# How to refresh React Flatlist after posting new Item to my Database?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-effect

I am trying to build a react-native application which is using aws api gateway/lambda and dynamodb as a backend. I have a flatlist which I am populating by making a call to retrieve all items from a database. I have an effect hook which I am using to fetch the data when the component mounts. How do I make the same effect run when/if my post request is successful ?

This is my effect hook which I am running only once like component did mount.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const resp = await fetch('MY_AWS_URL')
      const data = await resp.json()
      const exp = data.Items 
      setExp(exp);   //SET THE STATE VARIABLE WITH THE DATA
      setLoading(false); //STOP DISPLAYING DEFAULT SPINNER AND SHOW DATA
    }
    fetchData();

  }, []);
```

I Have a form which will allow me to post new data to the database. How do I automatically refresh my component to display the latest data if my POST request is successful ?

Answer (score 1):

try to put the list in the state, and after you call the post request, update the state (list of item) with the newest item, so react will update your component
i give you here an exemple with axios library, if you don't work with it, it's not a problem, just update the list after your post request executed successfully

```js
class yourClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: [],//list contain the same data in your database
    };
  }
  const update = () =>{
  axios().post().then(setState({list:nextlisteWithTheNewItem})).catch()
  }

  render() {
  
  }
```

Comment: This isn't very helpful, perhaps, take his code and give an example of what you are trying to convey?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-navigation your componentDidMount(useEffect) only will trigger one time because the component not unmount.
So I think you are redirecting from your createItem screen to showItems screen so
you should use focus listener and call your backend when your screen is focused (basically this mean when you are in that screen)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

function ItemScreen({ navigation }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // The screen is focused
      // Call any action
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const resp = await fetch('MY_AWS_URL')
      const data = await resp.json()
      const exp = data.Items 
      setExp(exp);   //SET THE STATE VARIABLE WITH THE DATA
      setLoading(false); //STOP DISPLAYING DEFAULT SPINNER AND SHOW DATA
    }
    fetchData();
    });

    // Return the function to unsubscribe from the event so it gets removed on unmount
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  return <View />;
}
```